# iOS game Localization with String Format

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization

I want to localize strings with numbers inside a sentence. I dont use iOS's Localizable.strings file since it's tedious and error prone and I may decide to rephrase words later on.

Here is what I did:

```
#define sf_buy_bombs @"Are you sure you want to buy %i bombs for $%i? "
```

where 'sf' suffix means 'string format'

here is when i need to use it:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: [Helper getLocalizedStringWithString:sf_buy_bombs], num_shop_items_bundle, price_bombs]
```

and a helper method to handle the translation

```
+(NSString*) getLocalizedStringWithString: (NSString*) str {
    if ([Helper isSimplifiedChinese]) {
        if ([str isEqualToString:sf_buy_bombs]) {
            return @"确定要购买%i个炸弹道具吗? ($ %i)";
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

The final label displayed is "确定要购买%i个炸弹道具吗? ($ %i)", the number are not substituted in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Helper class

```
#define sf_buy_bombs @"Are you sure you want to buy %i bombs for $%i? "
```

and

```
+(NSString *)localizedStringWithString{
    return sf_buy_bombs;//all other stuffs 
}
```

In the required class:

```
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:[Helper localizedStringWithString],10,100];
NSLog(@"%@",string); //gives correct output as checked by me as :

//Are you sure you want to buy 10 bombs for $100?
```

**EDIT: with your Chinese font string:** [Find working Model here.](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/6141966/chinese-macro-88k?da=y)

[image]

Comment: what is Array class ur referring to

Comment: Sorry for my testing i used Array, in your case it is Helper. Also check for the method name, I have skipped `get`

Comment: dude, that's what i did. if it's english i return the original string and numbers are sub'ed in. but if it go through translation process and return 确定要购买%i个炸弹道具吗? ($ %i), the numbers are not sub'ed in anymore

Comment: Weird. im doing the same thing

Comment: @OMGPOP: should i send you my working code?

Comment: nah I copied the code and i works now. anyways thanks. i guess my code is too messy