# Can't print out non-ascii text in Xcode console

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Not sure if anyone get me help. I create some array in plist. Its content was wrote by Chinese. It printed out the weird wordings in console through NSLog.

In console:

```
address = "\U65b0\U754c\U9752\U8863\U9577\U767c\U90a8\U9577\U767c\U5546\U5834232\U865f\U8216";
```

I have searched around web, but can't figure it out. Does anybody know to fix it?
Thank

Comment: not sure...try converting it to utf8 string

Comment: i don't think it is possible. but you can use some python or other script to convert these into proper character

Comment: have a look here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881425/ios-game-localization-with-string-format/15881654#15881654

Comment: Note that the NSLog of a dictionary prints `\Unnnn` escape sequences for many non-ASCII characters. Most probably the actual string is correct and you need not to convert anything.

Comment: You can save data in your NSSTRING object and while in debug mode try to print it. It will give you real data. This is working for me  in arabic contents.

Answer (score 0):

I tried logging an array containing arabic text, first time gave me the same result as it gave you.

```
NSArray *array = @[@"تليفونات محمولة",@"تليفونات محمولة",@"تليفونات محمولة",@"تليفونات محمولة",@"تليفونات محمولة"];

NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

The result was this:

```
 (
"\U062a\U0644\U064a\U0641\U0648\U0646\U0627\U062a \U0645\U062d\U0645\U0648\U0644\U0629",
"\U062a\U0644\U064a\U0641\U0648\U0646\U0627\U062a \U0645\U062d\U0645\U0648\U0644\U0629",
"\U062a\U0644\U064a\U0641\U0648\U0646\U0627\U062a \U0645\U062d\U0645\U0648\U0644\U0629",
"\U062a\U0644\U064a\U0641\U0648\U0646\U0627\U062a \U0645\U062d\U0645\U0648\U0644\U0629",
"\U062a\U0644\U064a\U0641\U0648\U0646\U0627\U062a \U0645\U062d\U0645\U0648\U0644\U0629"
)
```

but when tried this it printed out the correct string.

```
    NSLog(NSLocalizedString([array componentsJoinedByString:@" , "],nil));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this python script to decode the the characters

```
>>> def printUtf8(str):
...     str = str.lower()
...     exec 'print u"'+str+'"'
...
>>> printUtf8("\U65b0\U754c\U9752\U8863\U9577\U767c\U90a8\U9577\U767c\U5546\U5834232\U865f\U8216")
新界青衣長發邨長發商場232號舖
```

Comment: Could you explain how to add the python scripts to Xcode LLDB interactive GUI session?

Comment: Oop..I don't know python script. >_<  I have changed it to be NSString object to figure out.

    for (NSDictionary*tempDict in sectionHeaderArray) {
        
            NSDictionary*name=[sectionHeaderArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSString*tempNameString=[name objectForKey:@"name"];
            NSLog(@"%@",tempNameString);
            NSString*tempAddString=[name objectForKey:@"address"];
            NSLog(@"%@",tempAddString);
            NSString*tempHrString=[name objectForKey:@"officeHour"];
            NSLog(@"%@",tempHrString);
        }

Thank for everyone help.

Comment: @voromax i just provide a possible solution to intertep the output. and i am not sure excetly how do intergrade it into xcode. but lldb allows you to use python to debug the program. http://lldb.llvm.org/scripting.html